# ReactJS ESlint hook error React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am getting an error from ESlint regarding how I am using hooks when rendering my React component.

`React Hook "useReactiveVar" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render` [.eslintreact-hooks/rules-of-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Below is my code. How can I resolve this?

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useApolloClient, useReactiveVar } from '@apollo/client';
import isClient from 'commons/isClient';

import useVisitorLocationHook from '../useVisitorLocationHook';
import ClosestOrderSampleValue from './ClosestOrderSampleValue';
import storesData from './stores.json';

const useClosestStoreOrderSample= () => {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const { closestOrderSampleValueVar } = isClient() ? client.cache.jbReactiveVars : {};
  const { loading = false, OrderSampleValue = null, forUserZip = null } = isClient()
    ? useReactiveVar(closestOrderSampleValueVar)
    : {};
  const [userLocation] = useVisitorLocationHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userLocation?.zip || userLocation?.zip === forUserZip) {
      return;
    }
    ClosestOrderSampleValue.fetchClosestOrderSampleValuecode(client, userLocation.zip);
  }, [userLocation]);

  return {
    storeLocation: isClient() && OrderSampleValue ? storesData[OrderSampleValue] : null,
    isOrderSampleValueLoading: !userLocation?.zip ? false : loading,
  };
};

export default useClosestStoreOrderSample;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the rules of hooks, you can't conditionally calla hook. So this line:

```
const { loading = false, OrderSampleValue = null, forUserZip = null } = isClient()
    ? useReactiveVar(closestOrderSampleValueVar)
    : {};
```

is causing the error.

You need to ensure that you call `useReactiveVar()` without condition. For example, you could do this instead:

```
const clientData = useReactiveVar(closestOrderSampleValueVar);
const {
    loading = false,
    OrderSampleValue = null,
    forUserZip = null,
} = isClient() ? clientData : {};
```

This will make sure that you always call the hooks in the same and correct order. This is necessary as React uses the order in which hooks are called to ensure it updates the correct state through each render. [You can read more information (with examples) on this here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer James, Just want to ask why/reason for using `useMemo()`?

Comment: I'm using `useMemo` to ensure that the values returned are only re-evaluated if the contents of `clientData` changes, although now that I think about it, the Object in the dependency Array will still cause the `useMemo` to re-evaluate, so I will actually update my answer.